# Unexpected token in \android\build.gradle line: 14 : unexpected token: {

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When trying to build the project using

> flutter build apk --split-per-abi
> I however get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\proeject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 34
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\proeject\android\app\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\project\android\app\build.gradle': 34: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 34, column 9.
> android {
> ^

1 error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

**My Code :**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.company.project"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName 1.0.0
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../keystore/key.jks')
            storePassword file('../keystore/keystore.password').text.trim()
            keyPassword file('../keystore/keystore.password').text.trim()
            keyAlias 'key'
    }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will solve your problem but I was also facing the same issue. But I don't know why configuring the unsecured way solved my problem. I just replace the below code :

```
   release {
    storeFile file('your_key_name.keystore')
    storePassword System.console().readLine("\nKeystore password:")
    keyAlias System.console().readLine("\nAlias: ")
    keyPassword System.console().readLine("\Alias password: ")
   }
```

with

```
release {
  storeFile file('your_key_name.keystore')
  storePassword 'your_key_store_password'
  keyAlias 'your_key_alias'
  keyPassword 'your_key_file_alias_password'
}
```

It worked for me.